# Use custom class as conditions in tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

Can I make a condition in the tailwind that if the parent has a class for example "small", then this element will have the property "p-0" used. Is it possible to implement this without writing all the options in css, but using something like this: "parent-small: p-0"

I tried to just add the necessary classes to the style file, but this results in a lot of monotonous classes, and I would like to know if it is possible to do this using tailwind

Comment: cannot you use the breaking points provided : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design ?

Comment: You might want to check @apply: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply

Comment: it would be `sm:p-0` i believe  :)

Comment: I have the class "small" added to the parent depending on the state to make the sidebar shorter and all the elements in it smaller, so i can't use sm:...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! You could consider using a [`group` variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state) like:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="group">
  <div class="p-10 bg-red-200 group-[.small]:p-0">
    Foo
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group small">
  <div class="p-10 bg-green-200 group-[.small]:p-0">
    Bar
  </div>
</div>
```